# Getting REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD in netbeans when trying to push to server

Tags: git, netbeans

I am a new git user.

I have a repository on bitbucket that I would like to import into a .git folder I have created on my live shared host web server ( where I have git installed ). I can give commands via SSH. I am following the instructions in http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

I have been able to set up the 2 repos on the server as described in the article. I also have the post update and post commit hooks in place. I am trying to test the system by pushing an update to the server. I am using netbeans 7.3 beta git support. However when give the command:

```
push ( in netbeans ) to ssh://****.com/home/******/site_hub.git
```

The output is:

```
==[IDE]== Nov 19, 2012 10:28:15 PM Pushing
git push ssh://***.com/home/***/site_hub.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : 0121897bdd7cf3caad9e18717fc27a7a08***
New Id : 837c194c70fb41dc7de3be7841c946ca***
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
No update
==[IDE]== Nov 19, 2012 10:28:18 PM Pushing finished.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 47):

A non-fastforward push means the branch your are trying to push to diverged from the point your current branch is. In other words, there are new commits in your remote that you have to merge with to be able to push.

To achieve this, you can `git pull` in order to merge both branches, and then push the result, or you can do a `git fetch` and then a `git rebase origin/master` (or whatever names you put to your remote and HEAD branch) so your commits are applied on top of the remote branch. Then you can push the result, and that would be a fast-forward.

Comment: following your directions I pulled from my server repository then pushed back to it. here is the output:   ==[IDE]== Nov 20, 2012 12:24:19 AM Pulling...
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git pull ssh://***.com/home/***/site_hub.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
==[IDE]== Nov 20, 2012 12:24:27 AM Pulling... finished.
==[IDE]== Nov 20, 2012 12:30:16 AM Pushing

Comment: git push ssh://****.comt/home/***/site_hub.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : 0121897bdd7cf3caad9e18717fc27a7a08ee7f11
New Id : 837c194c70fb41dc7de3be7841c946ca75fc8d79
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD
Local Repository Updates
No update
==[IDE]== Nov 20, 2012 12:30:29 AM Pushing finished.

Comment: @user61629 So you'll have to `git rebase` your branch onto `origin/master`. Try running `git rebase origin/master` while on your `master` branch, and then `git push`.

Comment: does it matter that this is a bare repository? (please see article) when I go to server and run git status I get  fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Comment: when I try git rebase origin/master while the hub directory , I get : fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-rebase cannot be used without a working tree.

Comment: @user61629: You have to run the `rebase` in your local clone of the repository, not in the bare one. `rebase` rewrites your commit history in a different way, so then you can push them to the bare server without loosing any of the pre-existing commits. Bare repositories don't have working directories, and that's why you can't `rebase` (`rebase` operations could lead to conflicts and blobs editing, and you need a working directory for doing that).

Answer (score 1):

In my case doing the following seemed to do the trick

```
git checkout master

git pull
```

In my case when I switched back to master I got this

> Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 8 commits, and can be
>   fast-forwarded.   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

I'm thinking this is probably the same ish as mgarciaisaia answered but I wanted to post in case it might help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my report for NONFASTFORWARD problem

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:53:22 AM Pushing - Mycology  Pro finished.
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:54:19 AM Create Branch
git branch --track Master_v2.0 master
Branch created
Name: Master_v2.0
From: master
Id  : 1dac54d97af9be9e2d4e78ed1550ed486d26a76f
git show conflicts
git checkout Master_v2.0
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:54:19 AM Create Branch finished.
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:54:58 AM Fetching - Mycology  Pro
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git fetch https://larry-mintz@github.com/larry-mintz/MycoForms.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
No update
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:54:59 AM Fetching - Mycology  Pro finished.
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:55:27 AM Pushing - Mycology  Pro
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://larry-mintz@github.com/larry-mintz/MycoForms.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : d3c98e3ac615861a1747759639f878ba8f235f38
New Id        : 1dac54d97af9be9e2d4e78ed1550ed486d26a76f
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

I  tried everything .In the end I did this:

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Add : Master_v2.0
Id         : 1dac54d97af9be9e2d4e78ed1550ed486d26a76f
Result     : OK

Local Repository Updates
Branch Add : origin/Master_v2.0
Id         : 1dac54d97af9be9e2d4e78ed1550ed486d26a76f
Result     : NEW

==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:57:17 AM Setting Tracked Branch
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:57:17 AM Pushing - Mycology  Pro finished.
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/Master_v2.0 Master_v2.0
Branch "Master_v2.0" marked to track branch "origin/Master_v2.0"
==[IDE]== 3-Dec-2017 11:57:17 AM Setting Tracked Branch finished.